# Django not auto-filling a new html file

Tags: python, html, django, visual-studio-code

starting to learn django, and in the video im watching django automatically fills minimum html code when you create a new html file in the templates folder, but its not happening for me. i can switch to HTML language mode and ctrl+space & choose HTML_sample, but its not the same code as shown in the video.
is it just a pycharm thing? the video uses pycharm, but they say the Django autofills the code so didnt think it was the issue.

the html files path: "project_name\app_name\templates\app_name"
using VScode 3.9 and django 3.2.5.
(had some trouble with django-html, had to add it manually to the settings.json)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall or Disable Django extension on VS code and it should solve the problem

[Type "html:5" to get the emmet suggestion, if it doesn't appear, just type "html:5" and hit Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0NXG.png)

Comment: Tried that, still didnt auto-fill it but now it didnt set it to html at all (plain text)

Comment: Can you send me the link to the video, so I can see what sample code you are referring too?

Comment: In visual studio code whenever, you want an html file, you have to state what file you are creating. It doesn't automatically create the file with the sample code. I'll edit my response above